# Making computations on pairs of sub events in two large files

Tags: c++

I have large data in two files each with about two million (different) entries. The structure of the file is such that there is an event number, and for each event, there are some subevents. Each of these subevents have some characteristics. For example, the general structure of the files is such:

```
Index  Event     SubEvent      Characteristic1          Characteristic2 .... 
  1      1            1                 322                      234
  2      1            2                 453                      324
  3      1            3                 ...                      ...
  .      .            .                 ...                      ...
  .      .            .                 ...                      ...
 100     1           100                ...                      ...
 101     2            1                 ...                      ...
 102     2            2                 ...                      ...
  .      .            .                 ...                      ...
  .      .            .                 ...                      ...   
  .      .            .                 ...                      ... 
 207     2           107                ...                      ...
 208     3            1                 ...                      ...
 209     3            2                 ...                      ...
```

and so on, the index runs till about two million.

I have two Files, lets call them `file1` and `file2`, with the above structure. I have to make some computations using their characteristics for each subevent of an event. Here's the outline of what I have thought up.

```
LOOP over each INDEX in file1
LOOP over each INDEX in file2
if (Event value of file1 is same as event value of file2)
/* do some computations with characteristics and store them somewhere*/
```

The current implementation I have written

```
for (int i=0;i<nEntries_1;i++)  {
        file1->GetEntry(i);
         for (int_t j=0; j < nEntries_2 ; j++)    {
                file2->GetEntry(j);
                if (event1 != event2) break;
               else {
               /* Doing the computation with characteristics*/
               }      
               }
               }
```

However I think that this is wrong. Suppose we are at index 209 in the top file1 loop. Which means it needs to compute some characteristic for subevent 2 in event 3 of `file1` with all the subevents of event3 in `file2`. However, the above code would break out of the loop as the event numbers of the first entry would not match.

What could be a possible solution. If I just do a brute force with no `if-break` command it takes way too long.

Comment: You don't want `break`, but rather `continue`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Thanks. You are right, I looked over the command and that is what I need. But it is taking too much time. Its been about 3 minutes and the code is still on index 90 of the first file (there are 2 million indices in each file). Is there anyway to make this faster?

Comment: I have just made a calculation, this will take 1000 hours. This is hopeless, I would have to look into turning the data into a seperate format. @Kerrek could you post your comment as an answer.

Comment: How deep does it nest, and how many SubEvents are there per Event? If it is just one level deep, and there are many SubEvents per event (say many particle tracks), the way to do it in ROOT is to create a Branch of a TClonesArray of your objects. You can store a varying number of objects per event there. ... If it nests deeper, say event->subevent->subsubevent->..., then you might be better off with your own data structure, like a tree (not a ROOT TTree, which is something completely different)...

Comment: Hmm I just see, this was a month ago. I hope you found a solution already :-).

Comment: @jdm I was able to do it using a TClonesArray. I adapted the example posted on the [website](http://root.cern.ch/root/html/tutorials/tree/tcl.C.html) to my code and it works fine. However, this solution was adhoc and did not really contribute much to my understanding. Do you know of any resources where I can learn, for example, what is meant by "...create a brach of a TClonesArray" as you said in the comment. (And please do not suggest the ROOT manual, which is the worst documentation I have read, or atleast a bit too advanced for me.)

Comment: @yayu Not really... there is no good tutorial that explains that. I learned it by reading a lot of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop you have to say `continue` to skip a round, rather than your `break` which aborts the entire loop.

Design-wise, your algorithm is extremely inefficient, as you can convince yourself by doing a basic complexity analysis. Indexing your data suitably would almost certainly be necessary.

This is exactly what databases are for. I recommend you rig up a small database (e.g. MySQL), make two tables and run a JOIN query on the data, which should be a *lot* more efficient than your manual loop.

Alternatively, if you like to give it a try yourself, you could build your own micro-database in C++ with a structure like `std::multimap` and then use `euqal_range()` to do targetted matching.