# CERN ROOT Making a Tree with event headers

Tags: root-framework

I need to make a Tree with event headers. I read from a ROOT file into two ntuples. Each of these ntuples had the following format:

```
Index  Event     SubEvent      Characteristic1          Characteristic2 .... 
  1      1            1                 322                      234
  2      1            2                 453                      324
  3      1            3                 ...                      ...
  .      .            .                 ...                      ...
  .      .            .                 ...                      ...
 100     1           100                ...                      ...
 101     2            1                 ...                      ...
 102     2            2                 ...                      ...
  .      .            .                 ...                      ...
  .      .            .                 ...                      ...   
  .      .            .                 ...                      ... 
 207     2           107                ...                      ...
 208     3            1                 ...                      ...
 209     3            2                 ...                      ...
```

and so on, the index runs till about two million.

The format I used to create the ntuples:

```
TNtuple *tp = new TNtuple("tp","tp","x:y:z");
TNtuple *tn = new TNtuple("tn","tn","x:y:z");

for(Int_t n = 0; n < nEvents; n++) {
    inTree->GetEntry(n);
    Int_t nTracks = trackArray->GetEntries();
    for(Int_t i = 0; i < nTracks; i++) {
    Track* trackData = (Track*)trackArray->At(i);
        if(trackData->fCharge == 1)
        tp->Fill(trackData->x,trackData->y,trackData->z);
        if(trackData->fCharge == -1)
            tn->Fill(trackData->x,trackData->y,trackData->z);
        }
    }
```

However, with ntuples I have the problem that the analysis that I want to do on it becomes impossibly time consuming. I would like to have my data structured in the same way as the data I am reading, i.e a tree with two braches (for my two "files") and each containing an even header, so that I can loop over the events in one file and subsequently nest a loop over the second file only for the same events. Related to [previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141427/making-computations-on-pairs-of-sub-events-in-two-large-files/7141632#7141632)

I do not have the code for how the original file was constructed, which allowed the above way of writing data possible.

Comment: Are you compiling this code or running it with CINT?

Answer (score 0):

Two millions is not so much.

1. Try to switch off branches that you don't need.
2. Change the second `if` to `else if`
3. In addition you can use Proof